# How do I read inconsistent nvarchar data as decimal data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

For `SSRS 2005` report how do i read inconsistent `nvarchar` data values from database as consistent numeric decimal data for plotting a line chart?

the `nvarchar` column has lab readings to be plotted on a graph as `nvarchar(15)` datatype.

sample column with inconsistent data as shown

```
columnvalues
00123
102
(NULL)
333
456
N/R
No Result
567
589
```

Comment: You should take this one over to http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: This is a duplicate, already answered.

Answer (score 0):

My boss helped me with this query. You can add more clauses at the end of the following query depending on the inconsistencies in your data.

use database
go
select convert(decimal (10,2), ltrim(rtrim(columnname)))  from table
where isnumeric(columnname) = 1
and ltrim(rtrim(columnname)) <> '.'

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your table is LabData and your numeric column is named LabReading:

```
SELECT
    LabReadingValue =
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(LabReading)=1
            THEN CAST(LabReading AS DECIMAL(15,4))
            ELSE NULL 
        END
FROM
    LabData
```

If you want to filter out the non-numeric values, you can add:

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC(LabReading)=1
```